# Symfony 2.0 General questions

Tags: symfony

I would like to develop a website for a company with a lot of different functions. I decided to use the Symfony 2.0 framework for the first time and started reading the documentation and also a video tutorial.
After a week reading the documentation I still have some general questions unanswered. It would be great if you could help me with them:

- Which client OS do you recommend to work with Symfony2? Windows doesn't seam appropriate.
- Can I develop the whole website on a local Apache server and than upload the files to a regular webhosting server and use it?
- I bought a regular web hosting (www.cyon.ch) is this recommended? I can't use any console on it.

I'm really confused and I'm sure I'm asking quite some stupid questions. It would be great if you can help me understand better how Symfony2 works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Symfony works on any platform using PHP. 2. Yes, you can, thought this is not optimized since you'll have to send the vendor folder each time you upgrade them. Make sure to filter out `.git` folders. Moreover, you'll have to clear the cache for the prod environnement before deploying it. 3. No, it's not recommanded. The usage of the console makes the production deployement easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows is OK, as long as you have PHP and MySQL. There are several package that can do the job.
2. You can. In fact you should. Common workflow is develop on localhost and test on test server, and then move to production server. You should use a SCM like git.
3. Theoretically you can. But you won't have access to many console features that are really useful, like updating the database schema, flushing cache, download dependecies automatically, etc. I know some people doing this (copying everything with vendors), that's heavy and insecure.

   When it takes half a day to update the app, you don't hurry when you have to apply security patch. Unlike Wordpress or Drupal, Symfony has no other 'easy way' to update vendors and third party modules than command line interface. So it is really not a good idea. You can find a lot of VPS with full ssh access, that cost less than 10$ months.

Comment: Two more question arise:
- When I search for a host, I only have to check if he has full ssh access, that should be enough?
- I know github a bit but not very well, are you suggesting to upload the whole code to github to have version control?
Thanks already!

Answer (score 1):

1. I work on windows just fine. For wamp server, use Easyphp. Everything is easy to configure and most important; cli and apache users use same php.ini
2. Yes, but it is bad. You should use either svn or git. I find svn easier to use and both of them have UI variants: TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGIT.
3. No. You need console access and php5.3 minimum.

Comment: You don't necessary need console and if you need it, you can use it in browser with a bundle like that https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle

Comment: I use git or svn to upload it to a repository and the repository is on my host? or upload it to e.g. github to have version control and run it locally with apache or wamp?
Thanks already for your help! I really appreciate it!